# Installing Multiple Postgresql instances

Tags: server, postgresql

I'm following this tutorial to install multiple version of Postgresql on Ubuntu 16.04 to test streaming replication
http://blog.endpoint.com/2012/08/using-different-postgresql-versions-at.html

But I installed both 9.5 and 9.6 with this command line:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.5 postgresql-9.6 postgresql-client-common
```

But when I try to do `psql --cluster 9.5/main --version` and `psql --cluster 9.6/main --version` both give me the same answer

> psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.5

which means there is only one instance that is accessible.

Comment: At some point (post instructions?) the default install port changed to the next port (5433 instead of 5432). Maybe you need to specify the ports?

Comment: I know that they are on different ports. But how do I specify the port number when I'm using the command psql?

Comment: Ok so I tried psql --cluster 9.5/main -p 5432 --version with port numbers from 5432 up to 5435 and the result is the same.

Comment: Please run `pg_lsclusters` to display the list and status of the PG clusters as known by the `pg_wrapper` layer.

Answer (score 0):

According to  [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/pg_wrapper.1.html),

> psql, pg_archivecleanup, and pg_isready, pg_wrapper will always use the binary from the newest PostgreSQL version installed, as these are downwards compatible.

Hence when you run either `psql --cluster 9.5/main --version` or `psql --cluster 9.6/main --version` both give me the same answer